# Flutter POST with JSON Array

Tags: http, dart, flutter

I need to create a post request with a JSON that contains an Array. The `http.post` method only accepts `Map<String, String>`. Because of this, I cannot pass a Map with type `<String,dynamic>` since the Map will contain a List. Here's my code for an explicit `HttpClientRequest`:

```
String jsonString = json.encode(body); // encode map to json
List<int> bodyBytes = utf8.encode(jsonString); // utf8 encode
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpClientRequest request = await client.postUrl(uri);
// it's polite to send the body length to the server

request.headers.set('Content-Length', bodyBytes.length.toString());
request.headers.set('Authorization', '...');
request.headers.set('X-Authorization', apiKey);
request.headers.set("Accept", "application/json");
request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'form-data');
request.add(bodyBytes);
HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((contents) {
  // handle data
  return jsonDecode(contents);
});
```

The problem is, the above request fails.

EDIT:

The json that is created is:

```
{  
   "subject":"PLEASE",
   "message":"JUST. WORK.",
   "filter":"[8]",
}
```

But the JSON the server expects is:

```
{  
   "subject":"PLEASE",
   "message":"JUST. WORK.",
   "filter":[8],
}
```

My main concern is how does one create a JSON array...

Comment: Not sure I understand what the problem is. What does not work in the code above?

Comment: @Edman, fails to post. I get a null response, or an invalid data response.

Comment: It's good to spell out the errors you're getting in your question, and also point where in your code you're getting the error. Also, how is that null response related to `Map<String, dynamic>`?

Comment: @Edman, the http.post only accepts body of type Map<String,String>, but I need to post an array in the JSON. For this, I presume I need to use a client and explicitly create a post method, as mentioned in the doc.

Comment: It's also good to give a link to that doc then. You're encoding your `body` to `jsonString`, and that's what you're passing to the http client, which sounds right. I don't understand what you mean by "post accepts body of type Map<String, String>"; I don't see where you're passing this map, the post/postUrl methods don't take a map.

Comment: @Edman edited the question.

Comment: I ran `json.encode` in a map containing a string and a list, and it created the json output correctly, as expected. It didn't generate the `"filter":"[8]"`.

Comment: @Edman, fixed! I was converting the list to a string before adding to the map. Adding the list as is, seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. There were two main issues:

1. I was converting the `List` into a JSON string when adding to the `Map`. After only adding the `List` directly to the `Map`, it seemed to generate the correct JSON.
2. The content-type must be set to application/json in the request header.

Thanks @Edman for adding some direction.